# Change named pipe buffer size in macOS

Tags: c++, operating-system, pipe, named-pipes, darwin

Is there any way to control the buffer size of a named pipe created through `mkfifo`?

I’m using macOS 10.13.2 and the buffer size seems fixed at 8192 bytes. I was able to get to that number with this snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <thread>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024*1024
#define FIFO_PATH "/Users/joao/Desktop/fifo"

void readFifo() {
        auto fd = open(FIFO_PATH, O_RDONLY);

        if (fd < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to open fifo for reading" << std::endl;
                return;
        }

        std::cout << "Ready to read!" << std::endl;

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        auto total_bytes_read = 0;

        while (total_bytes_read < BUFFER_SIZE) {
                auto bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
                std::cout << "Read " << bytes_read << " bytes" << std::endl;

                total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
        }

        close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        unlink(FIFO_PATH);

        if (mkfifo(FIFO_PATH, 0666) != 0) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to create fifo" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        std::thread reader(readFifo);

        auto fd = open(FIFO_PATH, O_WRONLY);

        if (fd < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to open fifo for writing" << std::endl;
                return 1;
        }

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
                buffer[i] = 'a';
        }

        auto bytes_written = write(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

        reader.join();
        std::cout << "Wrote " << bytes_written << " bytes" << std::endl;

        unlink(FIFO_PATH);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not tried this, but on the command line in Terminal.app, `ulimit -a` reports the pipe size, and can be set using `ulimit -p`.

Comment: Found this related Q&A:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: @Eljay `ulimit -a` doesn't return the named pipe size on macOS. The related Q&A doesn't have an answer on how to change the value.

Comment: You change the value by editing pipe.h and sys_pipe.c and recompiling the operating system's kernel.

Comment: I feared that to be the only answer.